# Img Tag loading livestream after change of Component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using HTML `img` Tag to show a livestream which comes from an IP-Camera.
This works perfectly until you change to another component. Since I set the `src` to an empty string in `OnDestroy` I thought it would just stop the download. Just yesterday we found out that this is not the case and Chrome (and Edge) seem to still load the img/livestream after the change of components, which after some time heavily decreases the performance.

HTML:

```
<img class="livestream" src="{{livestreamUrl}}" />
```

TS:

```
public livestreamUrl: string;


  @Input() configuration: LivestreamConfig = undefined;

  constructor(
    private optionEventService: OptionEventService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.livestreamUrl = this.configuration.options.livestreamURL; //00.00.00.00/mjpg/1/video.mjpg
    this.select();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("destroy");
    
    this.livestreamUrl = "";
 }
```

Now I am curious if there is a way to just stop this "Download" or if this might be a bug in the network console.

A Screenshot of the Network Tab:
[image: Network Tab]

FYI: I have changed to an other component and back to the Livestream Component multible times which opens another download/request every time but doesn't end the old one (in Chorme at least).
[image: Chorme Network Tab]
The weird thing is that MS Edge seems to just use the old request again and doesnt open anotherone.
[image: Edge Network Tab]

EDIT:
Enabeling Cache seems to change behaviour: with Cache enabled it does not open another request!